# Having trouble with promises in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use promises with nodejs (I'm trying with node-promise package); however, without any success. See the code below:

```
var express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    promise = require('node-promise');

app.get('/promise', function(req, res) {
    var length = -1;

    new promise.Promise(request(
        {uri: "http://www.bing.com"},
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.log("An error occurred when connected to the web site");
                return;
            }

            console.log("I'll return: " + body.length);
            length = body.length;
        }
    )).then(function(result) {
        console.log("This is what I got: " + length);
        console.log("Done!");
    });

    res.end();
});
```

The output of the above code is `I'll return: 35857` only and it doesn't go to the `then` part.

I change the code then to be:

```
app.get('/promise', function(req, res) {
    var length = -1;

    promise.when(
        request(
            {uri: "http://www.bing.com"},
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    console.log("An error occurred when connected to the web site");
                    return;
                }

                console.log("I'll return: " + body.length);
                length = body.length;
            }
        ),
        function(result) {
            console.log("This is what I got: " + length);
            console.log("Done!");
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );

    res.end();
});
```

This time the output is `This is what I got: -1` then `Done!`... looks like the "promise" was not called this time.

So:

- What's needed to be done to fix the code above? Obviously I'm not doing it right :)
- Is node-promise "the way to go" when I'm doing promises, or is there a better way/package? i.e. simpler and more production-ready.

Thanks.

Comment: node-promise is the product of a very muddled mind.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, so what's the alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [jquery-deferred-for-node](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-deferred-for-node).

I'm not an expert but understand that this lib tends to be favoured by programmers who  work both server-side and client-side.

Even if you don't already know jQuery's Deferreds, the advantages of going this route are that :

- the documentation is excellent (it comprises links to the jQuery docs), though you may struggle to find examples specific to Node.
- methods are chainable.
- jQuery `Callbacks` are also included.
- when one day you need to do asynchronous stuff client-side, then there's virtually nothing to relearn - the concepts are identical and the syntax very nearly so. See the "Correspondances" section in the github page hyperlinked above.

### EDIT

I'm not a node.js person so I'm guessing here but based on your code above, you might want to consider something along the following lines with jquery-deferred-for-node :

```
var express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    Deferred = require('JQDeferred');

function fetch(uri, goodCodes) {
    goodCodes = (!goodCodes) ? [200] : goodCodes;

    var dfrd = Deferred(); // A Deferred to be resolved/rejected in response to the `request()`.
    request(uri, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var isGood = false;

            // Loop to test response.statusCode against `goodCodes`.
            for (var i = 0; i < goodCodes.length; i++) {
                if (response.statusCode == goodCodes[i]) {
                    isGood = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isGood) {
                dfrd.resolve(response.statusCode, body);
            } else {
                dfrd.reject(response.statusCode, "An invalid response was received from " + uri);
            }
        } else {
            dfrd.reject(response.statusCode, "An error occurred attempting to connect to " + uri);
        }
    });

    // Make promise derived from dfrd available to "consumer".
    return dfrd.promise();
};

//...

app.get('/promise', function(req, resp) {
    fetch("http://www.bing.com").done(function(statusCode, result) {
        console.log("Done! This is what I got: " + result.length);
    }).fail(function(statusCode, message) {
        console.log("Error (" + statusCode + "): " + message);
    });
    resp.end();
};
```

Here, I have tried to write a generalized utility for fetching a resource in such a way that the asynchronous response (or error) can be handled externally. I think this is broadly along the lines of what you were trying to achieve.

Out of interest, where do console.log() messages end up with node.js?

### EDIT 2

*Above, I have given `Deferred` an initial capital, as is conventional for Constructors*

With jQuery Deferreds, there must be any number of ways to fetch() consecutively. The approach below leaves `fetch()` as it was, and introduces `fetch_()` to act as its front-end. There may be simpler ways but this allows `fetch()` to remain a general utility, functionally equivalent to the client-side `jQuery.ajax()`.

```
function fetch_(uri){
    return function(){
        return fetch(uri, [200]).then(function(statusCode, result){
            console.log("Done! This is what I got: " + result.length);
        },function(statusCode, message){
            console.log("Error (" + statusCode + "): " + message);
        });
    };
}
```

Note that function `fetch()` returns a function. It has to be like this because where `fetch()` is called, we want an unexecuted function, not (yet) the result of that function.

Now let's assume an array of uris is available. This can be hard-coded or built dynamically - whatever the application demands.

```
var uris = [
    'http://xxx.example.com',
    'http://yyy.example.com',
    'http://zzz.example.com'
];
```

And now, a variety of ways in which `fetch_()` might be called :

```
//v1. To call `resp.end()` when the fetching process starts.
app.get('/promise', function(req, resp) {
    fetch_(uris[0])().then(fetch_(uris[1])).then(fetch_(uris[2]));
    resp.end();
});

//v2. To call `resp.end()` when the fetching process has finished.
app.get('/promise', function(req, resp){
    fetch_(uris[0])().then(fetch_(uris[1])).then(fetch_(uris[2])).always(resp.end);
});

//v3. As v2 but building a `.then()` chain of any (unknown) length.
app.get('/promise', function(req, resp){
    var dfrd = Deferred().resolve();//
    $.each(uris, function(i, uri){
        dfrd = dfrd.then(fetch_(uri));
    });
    dfrd = dfrd.always(resp.end);
});
```

*untested*

I have more confidence in v1 and v2. v3 may work.

v2 and v3 should both give exactly the same behaviour but v3 is generalized for any number of uris.

Everything may need debugging.

Comment: You really think [the jQuery Deferred Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) is good? Or do you have an other reference?

Comment: @Bergi, maybe I just got used to it but yes, I find it pretty good. Compared to the  node-promise documentation, it's a literary masterpiece. Possible improvements improvement would be a table summarising the differences between Deferreds and Promises and a clearer introduction to explain that these are the basic building blocks.

Comment: Yeah, the [node-promise readme](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise) is quite bad. Still, for jQuery I'm missing a technical exact reference for callbacks (with contexts and multiple arguments, for example) - I always have to look it up in the code. Also, the [doc for `.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) is not updated to its current behavior (`pipe`).

Comment: Mmm, documentation lag. I can't disagree with you there @Bergi. Last time I looked, there were still several mentions of `.bind()` in other methods' sections, despite being deprecated in its own section. What's good it the overall structure, indexing and search.

Comment: BlueSky, do I understand correctly from your edits that you've got this working?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, yes it worked on my local then and I was doing some extra tests on heroku. Thanks. I have one more question though; how can I chain promises which I want to execute consecutively? I mean after I `fetch` bing.com I want to `fetch` google.com and so on.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, regarding you question I run node on Windows and `console.log` print the message in the Console windows (Command Prompt). On heroku the seem to save it somewhere and I get it using `heroku logs` command run from the app directory.

Comment: BlueSky, see EDIT 2 for a possible way ahead.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, thanks for the examples. I haven't tested all of them but they seem to serve the purpose, especially v3.

Comment: BlueSky, that's good. I hope you can get something to work. BTW, It's not really protocol to edit answers offered to you. If people spot something obviously wrong or decide to implement something different, then they generally say so in a comment, such that the anwerer can choose to make his own edit if he/she chooses.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Q: https://github.com/kriskowal/q. I believe that it's used internally by other frameworks (like jQuery deferred implementation).

I believe that the documentation is "fine"; the syntax is consistent with other promise implementations... and it has a node adapter.

So your deferred style approach:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function (err, res) {
    if (!err) {
        deferred.resolve(res);
    } else {
        deferred.reject(err);
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Can be written more concisely as:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", deferred.makeNodeResolver());
return deferred.promise;
```